# The usage of lazy-sequences in clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I am wondering that lazy-seq returns a finite list or infinite list. There is an example,

```
(defn integers [n]
    (cons n (lazy-seq (integers (inc n)))))
```

when I run like

```
(first integers 10)
```

or

```
(take 5 (integers 10))
```

the results are 10 and (10 11 12 13 14)
. However, when I run

```
(integers 10)
```

the process cannot print anything and cannot continue.  Is there anyone who can tell me why and the usage of laza-seq. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say that you are running

```
(integers 10)
```

what you're really doing is something like this:

```
user> (integers 10)
```

In other words, you're evaluating that form in a REPL (read-eval-print-loop).

The "read" step will convert from the string `"(integers 10)"` to the list `(integers 10)`. Pretty straightforward.

The "eval" step will look up `integers` in the surrounding context, see that it is bound to a function, and evaluate that function with the parameter `10`:

```
(cons 10 (lazy-seq (integers (inc 10))))
```

Since a `lazy-seq` isn't realized until it needs to be, simply evaluating this form will result in a `clojure.lang.Cons` object whose `first` element is `10` and whose `rest` element is a `clojure.lang.LazySeq` that hasn't been realized yet.

You can verify this with a simple `def` (no infinite hang):

```
user> (def my-integers (integers 10))
;=> #'user/my-integers
```

In the final "print" step, Clojure basically tries to convert the result of the form it just evaluated to a string, then print that string to the console. For a finite sequence, this is easy. It just keeps taking items from the sequence until there aren't any left, converts each item to a string, separates them by spaces, sticks some parentheses on the ends, and voilà:

```
user> (take 5 (integers 10))
;=> (10 11 12 13 14)
```

But as you've defined `integers`, there won't be a point at which there are no items left (well, at least until you get an integer overflow, but that could be remedied by using `inc'` instead of just `inc`). So Clojure is able to read and evaluate your input just fine, but it simply cannot print all the items of an infinite result.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print an unbounded lazy sequence, it will be completely realized, unless you limit [`*print-length*`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*print-length*).

Answer (score 0):

The `lazy-seq` macro *never* constructs a list, finite or infinite. It constructs a `clojure.lang.LazySeq` object. This is a nominal sequence that wraps a function of no arguments (commonly called a thunk) that evaluates to the actual sequence *when called*; but it isn't called until it has to be, and that's the purpose of the mechanism: to delay evaluating the actual sequence.

So you can pass endless sequences around as *evaluated* `LazySeq` objects, provided you never *realise* them. Your evaluation at the REPL invokes realisation, an endless process.

Answer (score -1):

It's not returning anything because your integers function creates an infinite loop.

```
(defn integers [n]
  (do (prn n)
      (cons n (lazy-seq (integers (inc n))))))
```

Call it with `(integers 10)` and you'll see it counting forever.